# How to use tensorflow serving to serve a specific model method?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

In the tensorflow serving [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#predict_api), is there a way to specify a model method (other than the standard call or regress) that you want to run inference with?
Specifically, I am trying to use the [query_with_exclusions](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/api_docs/python/tfrs/layers/factorized_top_k/ScaNN?hl=en#query_with_exclusions) method from [SCaNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/api_docs/python/tfrs/layers/factorized_top_k/ScaNN?hl=en#query_with_exclusions).

I can serve the model's call function already using the Google's conveniently provided [SCaNN image](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann/tf_serving).

I guess I could create a separate servable with the query_with_exclusions method as its call function? (like [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/building-rest-api-tensorflow-serving-part-1.html)), but its seems like there should be a simpler way.

thanks for your help!